# gRPC documentation generator

Tags: documentation-generation, grpc

Does gRPC support generating documentation for services like Swagger?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[protoc-gen-doc](https://github.com/sourcegraph/prototools/blob/master/README.doc.md) is a `protoc` plugin which generates HTML docs using Go HTML templates. Although it [isn't being used by the original sponsor company](https://github.com/sourcegraph/prototools/issues/13#issuecomment-263610636) anymore, it looks like a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Your protofiles are the documentation.
You can put comments there to clarify meaning of parameters or service methods.

Comment: I suppose the proto file can be the source of documentation, but it'd still desirable to generate a pretty looking HTML with links between message types, service call examples and all that good stuff.

Comment: Googling `generate html documentation for grpc` gives the link [link](https://github.com/sourcegraph/prototools) which you can try to use.
Apart from that, you can generate documentation from the source code that was generated from protofiles. E.g. in java generated source all comments from your .proto file will appear in javadocs.

Answer (score 1):

I started working on a new open source documentation tool called [Sabledocs](https://github.com/markvincze/sabledocs) for generating docs for Protobuf and gRPC contracts.

You can use it by generating a binary descriptor of your Protobuf files:

```
protoc *.proto -o descriptor.pb --include_source_info
```

Installing the `sabledocs` CLI. (Requires Python >=3.11)

```
pip install sabledocs
```

And running the `sabledocs` command.

```
sabledocs
```

The documentation will be generated into a folder `sabledocs_output`, its main page can be opened with `index.html`.

You can see a [demo of a generated documentation site here](https://markvincze.github.io/sabledocs/demo/), and find more info in the [repository](https://github.com/markvincze/sabledocs) and in this [blog post](https://blog.markvincze.com/introducing-sabledocs/).